# isolating the rows based on values of fields in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

small example:

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   13374
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13453   13670
chr1    HAVANA  gene    14363   29806
```

I am trying to filter the rows base on the 3rd column. in fact if the 3rd column is gene i will keep the entire row and filter out the other rows. here is the expected output:

expected output:

```
chr1    HAVANA  gene    14363   29806
```

I am trying to do that in `awk` using the following command but the results is empty. do you know how to fix it?

```
awk '{ if ($3 == 'gene') { print } }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotes in the script:

```
$ awk '{ if ($3 == "gene") { print } }' file
chr1    HAVANA  gene    14363   29806
```

or:

```
$ awk '{ if ($3 == "gene") print }' file
```

but you could just:

```
$ awk '$3 == "gene"'
```